# maven not compiling test code / not running test code

Tags: maven

I have a simple Mavenized Java Project with the [expected directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) an no "business" classes yet:

[image]

The `pom.xml` is rather mundane. It declares dependencies on JUnit4 and JUnit5, and the "surefire" plugin (enclosing `project` noise elided):

```
<properties>
    <junit5Version>5.1.0</junit5Version>
    <junit4Version>4.12</junit4Version>   
    <commonsCodecVersion>20041127.091804</commonsCodecVersion>
    <mavenCompilerPluginVersion>3.7.0</mavenCompilerPluginVersion>
    <junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion>1.1.0</junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion>
    <mavenSurefirePluginVersion>2.21.0</mavenSurefirePluginVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenCompilerPluginVersion}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>9</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenSurefirePluginVersion}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit5Version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit5Version}</version>

                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-maven/ -->

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commonsCodecVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit4Version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit5Version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Problem:

1. In the above I don't not scope the `junit:junit` and
   `org.junit.jupiter.junit-jupiter-api` dependencies to the `test`
   scope. Indeed, if I do that, `mvn compile` fails because it cannot
   find the symbols for JUnit4 and JUnit5. This is unexpected, I would
   expect it to not actually compile the test code at all. Indeed
   examples generally show restriction to the `test` scope. What's
   wrong?
2. If there is no restriction to the `test` scope, then `mvn compile` works, but `mvn test` doesn't run any tests. The surefire plugin seems to not sniff out any JUnit tests, neither 4's nor 5's. What's wrong here?

And finally, version info:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2
Maven home: /usr/local/java/maven
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: First remove this: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` cause you should follow the convention over configuration paradigm.

Comment: @khmarbaise Facepalm! I didn't notice it. This is actually a leftover from the Eclipse mavenizer. Removing it gives first, an error indirectly telling you to create directory `target/generated-sources/annotations`. After that, `mvn compile` finds nothing to compile. Which is expected as there are no "business" classes. `mvn test` in both scoped-to-test and not-scoped-to-test dependencies still finds no tests though.

Comment: Have you tested that on plain command line first ? Furthermore there shouldn't be an error if you don't production code..apart from that than you should simply remove the directories...and the issue related to surefire version and JUnit5...

Comment: @khmarbaise Tnaks. Yes, I want to make it work on the command line. Actually, everything worked fine in Eclipse but I don't know what plugin magic is being applied. So I'm going to try again with the hints provided.. soon.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Actually I have found convention over configuration to be a poor choice as defaults seem to change with the whim of each new maintainer. I have been bitten by this many times and choose to be explicit always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maven-surefire-plugin` 2.21.0 is not compatible with version 1.1.0 of the `junit-platform-surefire-provider`.

Either rollback `maven-surefire-plugin` to 2.19.1 or update `junit-platform-surefire-provider` to 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (or the 1.2.0 release if it's out).

The `pom.xml` to use if using the SNAPSHOT, with the Sonatype plugin repository configured:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestJava</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestJava</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>oss-sonatype</id>
      <name>oss-sonatype</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <properties>
    <junit5Version>5.1.0</junit5Version>
    <junit4Version>4.12</junit4Version>
    <mavenCompilerPluginVersion>3.7.0</mavenCompilerPluginVersion>
    <junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion>
    <mavenSurefirePluginVersion>2.21.0</mavenSurefirePluginVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenCompilerPluginVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenSurefirePluginVersion}</version>
        <!-- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-maven/ -->
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${junitPlatformSurefireProviderVersion}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5Version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5Version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit4Version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit5Version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Run `mvn -U test` to force a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories.

Comment: Indeed, and I found the report: [maven-surefire-plugin 2.21.0 does not detect JUnit tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1341). Tried rolling back to `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.19.1 while keeping `junit-platform-surefire-provider` at 1.1.0 : WORKS. Alternatively, tried with `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.21.0 and `junit-platform-surefire-provider` 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: WORKS.

Comment: I prefer to be patient and use the older surefire plugin. I like to keep pom.xml files as simple as possible.